# How to pass duplicate querystring keys into PagedListPager?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, query-string, pagedlist

I am using `PagedList` to present search results.

I want `PagedListPager` to include the current querystring values in the paging links.

(These are bound to a VM on the search `Action` so that the correct results are displayed on each page and the search form continues to display the search criteria.)

My problem occurs when @Html.EditorFor() includes a default "false" value for booleans.

The RouteValueDictionary concatenates duplicate KV pairs into a comma delimited string. So the querystring of my paging links end up like this:

`searchTitles=true,false`

But this doesn't bind nicely to the search action's VM, which appears to require this for correct boolean binding:

`searchTitles=true&searchTitles=false`

(When trying to redisplay the search form it tells me that "true,false" is not a valid boolean value.)

---

**PagedListPager Implementation**

```
// Maintains values of the current querystring so that they are passed through from page to page. Also enables bookmarking by the user.

RouteValueDictionary rvd = new RouteValueDictionary(ViewContext.RouteData.Values);
foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.Keys)
{
    rvd[key] = Request.QueryString[key].ToString();
}
rvd["pageSize"] = Model.PageSize;

<text>
    @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model,
        page => Url.Action(null, rvd.SetValue("page", page.ToString())),
        new PagedListRenderOptions
        {
            MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay = 6,
            LiElementClasses = new string[] { "ListControls__control" }
        })
</text>
```

Comment: Its unclear why you think you need this. Typically the controller method contains parameters for your values (e.g. `bool searchTitles`) and then you return that back to the view using a view model or `ViewBag` property and add it using `page => Url.Action(....., new { searchTitles = Model.SearchTitles }`

Comment: Firstly, there are a lot of search / filtering criteria. Secondly I may also want to disable some depending on user roles. And finally I quite fancied reusing the paging controls in a few different search result views.  Everything seems to be working nicely except for this problem with booleans.

Comment: The 'DefaultModelBinder` handles this by setting the first value, but ignoring any subsequent values with the same name. You just need to do the same. But it would be far easier to use a view model so that you can just use `page => Url.Action(....., new { Model }` which will correctly serialize all the values.

Comment: Ok thanks Stephen, I will rethink my approach to this. It would appear to be impossible to pass duplicate keys into `Url.Action()` . Is that correct as far as you know?

Comment: Well its possible (it would bind to `IEnumerable<bool>` - but that's not what you want). You have not shown enough info relating the the 'search criteria' or the controller method to give an answer.